# how to apply css on iframe code in css, javascript and jquery, html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've try this code for Iframe code css but it dosen't working... can you suggest me how to apply css for iframe..

```js
window.onload = function() {
   let myiFrame = document.getElementById("myiFrame");
   let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.form_generater_form_div .block_label {font-weight: bold !important;}</style>';
}
```

**OR**

```js
$("#myiFrame").on("load", function() {
  let head = $("#myiFrame").contents().find("head");
  let css = '<style>.form_generater_form_div .block_label {font-weight: bold !important;}</style>';
  $(head).append(css);
});
```

Comment: Manipulating the content of the iFrame will only work, if the content comes from the same domain as your script that is manipulating the content afaik.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)